# What is the difference between different compiling buttons in winedt?

Tags: winedt

I am on my first LaTeX homework using winedt. I have just written my hello world code and saved it properly. Now I am wondering which compiling button is the right one to build a PDF file among the five buttons PDFTeXify, PDFLaTeX, PDFTeX, TeXify and LaTeX buttons. How can I differ them?[image]

Comment: PDFLaTeX is the right one.

Comment: Welcome. Its name should contain the "words" "pdf" and "LaTeX"... (LaTeX exports a `.dvi` file... and I have never used "TeXify")

Comment: Googling "Difference of pdfLaTeX and LaTeX" or "Difference of pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX" gives you tons of things.